# Write a Circumflex Larger in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, unicode, font-size

I can write 'A circumflex' as a label on a graph in Python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':(0,3,4,0),'y':(3,0,4,3)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

df.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, label='A\u0302', linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')

for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
             ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(22)

legend = ax.legend(loc=0, ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, -.3, .6, 1),
           fancybox=True, shadow=False,
           framealpha=1, fontsize=22)

plt.setp(legend.get_title(),fontsize=22)
```

This gives:

[image]

How can I get the circumflex larger please?

Comment: Maybe `$\^{A}$`?

Comment: yes, or `$\hat{A}$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mr. T & tmdavison, either ***$^{A}$*** or ***$\hat{A}$*** work for some reason:

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':(0,3,4,0),'y':(3,0,4,3)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

df.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, label='$A\u0302$', linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')
df.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, label='$\^{A}$',   linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')
df.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, label='$\hat{A}$', linewidth=5, color='k', linestyle='-')

for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
             ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(22)

legend = ax.legend(loc=0, ncol=1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.9, -.3, .6, 1),
           fancybox=True, shadow=False,
           framealpha=1, fontsize=22)

plt.setp(legend.get_title(),fontsize=22)
```

Comment: You can try the single codepoint for `'Â'`  as well (or the equivalents `'\xc2'` or `'\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX}'`.   The display engine may have trouble handling decomposed code points.